# Wait for Provider to finish before entering State

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-injector, angularjs-provider

I'm trying to wait for the provider to finish initializing before ui-router goes on to load the state.

Every time you enter the state the camera should be enabled, and whenever it is left disabled again. I put this into a provider because it needs to be usable at the `module.config` level:

```
.provider("Camera", function CameraProvider() {
  function init() {
    //async enableCamera
  }
  function exit() {
    //disableCamera
  }
  function $get() {
    return { init: init, exit: exit };
  }
});
```

and the state:

```
var cam = DubCameraProvider.$get(); // this is a hack, but I don't know how to
$stateProvider
.state("CameraState", {
  url: "/camera",
  onEnter: cam.init,
  onExit: cam.exit,
  views: {
    "view": {
        // template: ...,
      controller: "ControllerUsingCamera"
  }
 }
```

I tried using `$q` to create a promise and the using `resolve` to wait for that, but at the `module.config` level $q cannot be injected (or I just don't know how to?).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q` can be injected in the resolve object of your state without a problem:

Config:

```
angular.module('app').config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider.state('root', {
            'url': '/',
            'controller': 'rootController',
            'templateUrl': 'root.html',
            'resolve': {
                'data': [
                    '$q',
                    '$timeout',
                    function ($q, $timeout) {
                        var deferred = $q.defer();
                        $timeout(function() {
                          deferred.resolve({
                            'value': 'Foo'
                          });
                        }, 5000);
                        return deferred.promise;
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('rootController', [
    '$scope',
    'data',
    function ($scope, data) {
        $scope.value = data.value;
    }
]);
```

Straight from the documentation on their wiki: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kJ99Hi0qWx7DJxOVzxgA?p=preview

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but got me on Track. Marking as final answer because it is more detailed than the one below.

Answer (score 1):

`resolve` comes with dependency injection. You could do:

```
$stateProvider.state("CameraState", {
    url: "/camera",
    onEnter: cam.init,
    onExit: cam.exit,
    views: {
        "view": {
            // template: ...,
            controller: "ControllerUsingCamera"
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        somethingAsync: function($q) {
            var promise = $q.all( /*bunch of promises*/ );
            return promise;
        }
    }
}
```